# Stopping then starting EC2 from command line

Tags: batch-file, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to stop and then immediately start (**NOT REBOOT**) my Amazon EC2 server from *within* my instance

I have CLI (Command Line Interface Tools) and am running a Windows 2012 server.

Basically, I want to *ec2-stop-instances* from a batch, and then *ec2-start-instances* right after. But I want the *start-instances* to run after a minute or so.

Is there a way to send the command and ask Amazon to wait a minute before it is run?

This way, running the batch script will stop then start the instance.

Again, I can't use reboot. For some reason, it does not work with my needs.

Comment: No you shouldn't do that within the instance.

Comment: Why?... ec2-reboot-instance _and_ ec2-stop-instance both work fine on their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand this post is 3 years old, but it is possible to do this now with the AWS CLI, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/stop-instances.html

> aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids
>
> aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids

This could also be done from a Lambda Function, and scheduled

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is to schedule running a command with AWS API

And it's currently not possible to do it so because AWS API lack this feature.

So you cannot achieve what you described without another EC2 instance/other server/service, to scheduling running the command with something `cron`-like.

(But perhaps it will be possible soon - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27382253/2693875) for info about it.)