# Architecture for scheduler jobs in AWS ECS

Tags: docker, scheduler, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I saw that coursers develop a scheduler for run job in the ECS AWS. As far as I know, it is not available for download. I know that AWS has a component called AWS Data Pipeline.
I search and not found another option to schedule jobs on ECS AWS.
Is there another third-part scheduler for ECS?

So my options until now are:

- AWS Data Pipeline
- Single machine with Cron installed (I didnt test this solution, and I dont know if it is viable)

Comment: I'm not sure if this would meet your requirements, but AWS Lambda now supports scheduled jobs so that may be an alternative or way to schedule the necessary API calls.

Answer (score 4):

I think the cleanest approach may be to use Scheduled AWS Lambda events to kickoff an ecs start-task
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

[AWS Lambda Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382009/aws-lambda-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: I went to do this and found that DataPipeline was actually easier: http://blog.ratelim.it/blog/cron-jobs-on-amazon-ecs-with-datapipeline

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement use custom scheduler like Mesos or Jenkins.