# Invoke AWS Lambda(s) regularly every 1 minute

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How can I invoke an AWS Lambda regularly, **specifically every 1 minute**?
The current functionality allows Lambdas to be setup with [5 minute trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27382253/358013), but I am looking for a much lesser time interval.
I thought of running the Lambda forever, but it looks like that can't be done since the
[`Maximum execution duration per request  300 seconds`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Removed previous answer and update]
Now, AWS Lambda provides a per minute frequency CloudWatch Events - Schedule as a trigger option.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

There was a session at AWS Reinvent in 2015 that covered this exact topic, you can watch it here on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhJxTIq81AU shows how to use lambda and cloudwatch to get that 1 minute frequency with no external dependencies.

> Do you need to run an AWS Lambda function on a schedule, without an
>   event to trigger the invocation? This session shows how to use an
>   Amazon CloudWatch metric and CloudWatch alarms, Amazon SNS, and Lambda
>   so that Lambda triggers itself every minute—no external services
>   required! From here, other Lambda jobs can be scheduled in
>   crontab-like format, giving minute-level resolution to your Lambda
>   scheduled tasks. During the session, we build this functionality up
>   from scratch with a Lambda function, CloudWatch metric and alarms,
>   sample triggers, and tasks.

I suspect that at some point AWS will allow the 1 minute interval without using this method, but this may hold you over in the mean time.

Comment: I will try that and see if that works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding another approach/solution:

We can use **AWS EventBridge** to trigger a Lambda in particular intervals.

Doc -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html

YouTube -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUhEKtLrGvo

Answer (score -4):

Using the boto module, you can have a lambda function run an invoke statement, invoking itself. The following will run every ~60 seconds. Of course make sure you assign an appropriate role with permissions. Also, note your limits.

```
import boto3,time
def lambda_handler(event, context):
 #do something
 time.sleep(60)
 client = boto3.client('lambda')
 response = client.invoke(FunctionName='YOUR-FUNCTION-NAME')
```

Comment: Hahaha. This is crazy. Must everything be serverless? At this rate, I'd rather spin up the cheapest EC2 nano @ max cost: £4 monthly.