# Scheduled AWS Lambda Task at less than 1 minute frequency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scheduled-tasks, aws-lambda

We are trying to develop a true lambda-based application in which certain tasks need to be performed at schedules of variable frequencies. They are actually polling for data, and at certain times of the day, this polling can be as slow as once every hour, while at other times, it has to be once every second. I have looked at the options for scheduling (e.g. [Using AWS Lambda with Scheduled Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents.html) and [AWS re:Invent 2015 | (CMP407) Lambda as Cron: Scheduling Invocations in AWS Lambda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhJxTIq81AU)), but it seems that short of spinning up an EC2 instance or a long-running lambda, there's no built-in way of firing up lambdas at a frequency of less than one minute. The lambda rate expression doesn't have a place for seconds. Is there a way to do this without an EC2 instance or long-running lambda? Ideally, something that can be done without incurring additional cost for scheduling.

Comment: Why don't you want to use some small EC2 instance in order to perform your frequent tasks? It could be even more profitably.

Comment: @VladimirMukhin thanks for the suggestion, I was actually thinking maybe there's something free out there :). I have alternate approaches in mind like yours and Jared Hatfields's in the answer.

Comment: I have added links to a couple of the places that I searched for an answer before posting here and would appreciate if the down-vote is removed.

Comment: you may want to take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35272821/266659

Comment: Why not simply creating 2 event schedulers? two of them will execute every minute so just start the second event after half a minute from the first event starting time.

Comment: @Nativ: How would you start the second one half a minute offset from the first? Manually? Even if you did, is it clear from the specs that aws would continue to trigger these precisely and that they wouldn't just drift together?

Comment: @thund Yes, I'd do it manually. I agree it is error prone so a different solution is to create a new lambda that invokes the other lambda from its code(so max flexibility is available). Now I'll ping this lambda every 10 minutes using CloudWatch rule (every 10 minutes because it's known that lambda's instance is kept alive for 15 minutes after invokation, so 10 minutes is for "just in case"..)

Comment: You can leverage Step Function for that. Look at [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/a-serverless-solution-for-invoking-aws-lambda-at-a-sub-minute-frequency/) blog post.

Answer (score 18):

You theoretically *can* wire up a high-frequency task-trigger without an EC2 instance or long-running lambda using an [AWS Step Function](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) executed by a CloudWatch Events scheduled event (see Emanuele Menga's [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/a-serverless-solution-for-invoking-aws-lambda-at-a-sub-minute-frequency/) for an example), but that approach would actually be *more* expensive than the other two options, according to my current (as of May 2019) estimates:

(assuming 1 year = **31536000** seconds)

#### Step Function:

- [$0.0250](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/pricing/) per 1000 state transitions
- 2 state transitions per tick (`Wait`, `Task`) + at least 1 per minute (for setup/configuration)
- `31536000 * (2 + 1/60) * 0.0250 / 1000` = **$1589.94**/year, or as low as **$65.70**/year for lower frequency trigger (2 ticks per minute)

#### Lambda Function:

- [$0.000000208](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/) per 100ms (for smallest 128mb function)
- `31536000 * 0.000000208 * 10` = **$65.595488**/year

#### EC2 Instance:

- `t3a.nano` is [$0.0047](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) per hour on-demand, or as low as [$0.0014](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/) using Spot instances
- 31536000 * 0.0047 / 3600 = **$41.172**/year, or **$12.264**/year using Spot instances

So there will be *some* scheduling cost, but as you can see the cost is not that much.

Comment: It should be noted a step function will automatically stop (Failed state) after 25k entries in its execution history log.  This can happen real quick for step functions with many states.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/bp-history-limit.html

Answer (score 8):

Currently lambda functions are invoked, at the very least, every 1 minute from Cloudwatch schedule events.

**A solution that might work would be the following:**

Setup an EC2 instance and from a program, that you will run as a background job, use the aws sdk to invoke your lambda function. Example:

```
while True:
  invoke lambda function via aws sdk
  sleep for x seconds
```

Comment: I assume that in aws you're going to pay for every second your lambda is sleeping for because it counts as execution time?

Answer (score 3):

At this point in time AWS Lambda allows functions to be scheduled to run every 5 minutes with a maximum execution time of 5 minutes.

This means if you want to run an AWS Lambda function at intervals less than every 5 minutes while not using EC2 you can take a two phased approach.  Create an AWS Lambda function to run every 5 minutes and have it actually run for the entire 5 minutes calling other AWS Lambda functions asynchronously at the appropriate time intervals.

This approach will cost you more since the first AWS Lambda function that runs for the entire 5 minutes will essentially be running continuously, but you can reduce the cost by having the smallest amount of RAM allocated.

---

**UPDATE**

CloudWatch Events now allow for schedules at a frequency of 1 minute.  This means you can now schedule a Lambda function to run every minute and have it run for up to a minute to achieve sub-minute accuracy.  It is important to note that scheduled events do not fire at the beginning of every minute so achieving exact sub-minute timing is still a bit tricky.

Comment: Thanks. Either this or the least expensive EC2. Will need to work out what's cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

Don't poll with lambda or you are better off using EC2 if you expect to spend more time polling than performing work. Lambda charges by execution time and polling is costly.

You really need an event driven system with Lambda. What determines when you poll?

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple hack though where you could use a setTimeout or setInterval.

i.e:

```js
    'use strict';
    async function Task() { 
      console.log('Ran at'+new Date())
    }
    const TIMEOUT = 30000;
    exports.handler = (event, context) => {
       return Promise.all([
          Task(), 
          new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
             let timeout = setTimeout(function() {
               Task().then(() => {
                 clearTimeout(timeout)
               })
             }, TIMEOUT);
          })
          
    ])
        
    }
```