# PIP Install: Cannot combine --user and --target

Tags: python, pip, command-line-interface

My goal is to install a package to a specific directory on my machine so I can package it up to be used with AWS Lambda.

Here is what I have tried:
`pip install snowflake-connector-python -t .`

`pip install --system --target=C:\Users\path2folder --install-option=--install-scripts=C:\Users\path2folder --upgrade snowflake-connector-python`

Both of these options have returned the following error message:
`ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'`

In order for the AWS Lambda function to work, I need to have my dependencies installed in a specific directory to create a .zip file for deployment. I have searched through Google and StackOverflow, but have not seen a thread that has answered this issue.

Update: This does not seem to be a problem on Mac. The issue described is on Windows 10.

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7013, https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Can+not+combine+%27--user%27+and+%27--target%27+

Answer (score 44):

We encountered the same issue when running `pip install --target ./py_pkg -r requirements.txt --upgrade` with Microsoft store version of Python 3.9.

Adding `--no-user` to the end of it seems solves the issue. Maybe you can try that in your command and let us know if this solution works?

`pip install --target ./py_pkg -r requirements.txt --upgrade --no-user`

Answer (score 9):

We had the same issue just in a Python course: The error comes up if Python is installed as an app from the Microsoft app store. In our case it was resolved after re-installing Python by downloading and using the installation package directly from the Python website.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `--no-user` at the end does work, and by far the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error recently. Adding my solution so that it might help someone facing the error due to the same reason.

I was facing an issue where all my pip installed packages were going to an older python brew installation folder.

As part of debugging, I was trying to install `awscli-local` package to user site-package using:

`pip install --user awscli-local`

Then I got:
`ERROR: cannot combine --user and --target`

In my case, it was due to the changes in pip config I had set some time back for some other reason.
I had set the 'target' config globally - removing which removed this error and my actual issue I was debugging for.

---

Check the following if solutions given above doesn't resolve your issue:

try the command:
`pip config edit --editor <your_text_editor>`

For me:
`pip config edit --editor sublime`

This will open the current config file where you can check if there's any conflicting configuration like the 'target' set in my case.

Answer (score 0):

similar issue resolved it by adding `--no-user`

```
AzureAD+Irfan@irfan MINGW64 ~/Documents/aws deployment package (main)
$ pip3 install fastapi -t .
ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'

AzureAD+Irfan@irfan MINGW64 ~/Documents/aws deployment package (main)
$ ^C

AzureAD+Irfan@irfan MINGW64 ~/Documents/aws deployment package (main)
$ pip3 install fastapi -t . --no-user
Collecting fastapi
  Using cached fastapi-0.92.0-py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting starlette<0.26.0,>=0.25.0
  Using cached starlette-0.25.0-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Collecting pydantic!=1.7,!=1.7.1,!=1.7.2,!=1.7.3,!=1.8,!=1.8.1,<2.0.0,>=1.6.2
  Using cached pydantic-1.10.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.2 MB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=4.2.0
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting anyio<5,>=3.4.0
  Using cached anyio-3.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (80 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.8
  Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting sniffio>=1.1
  Using cached sniffio-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, sniffio, idna, pydantic, anyio, starlette, fastapi
Successfully installed anyio-3.6.2 fastapi-0.92.0 idna-3.4 pydantic-1.10.5 sniffio-1.3.0 starlette-0.25.0 typing-extensions-4.5.0
```