# Trouble installing python packages to target folder (ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target')

Tags: python, pyperclip

I am going through "Automate the Boring Stuff" and I am using Mu as a text editor. I am trying to install a particular package called `pyperclip`.

Since Mu has its own Python environment, I am trying to install `pyperclip` into its `/pkgs` folder. I encounter the following error:

```sh
PS C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Mu\pkgs> pip install pyperclip --target "C:\Program Files\Mu\pkgs"

ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'
```

I have looked around on GitHub and previous posts on learnpython and I have not found similar troubles.

My major confusion is that it says I cannot combine `--user` but I did not type `--user`.

I have a feeling the solution is elementary, but I am learning python and how to work with terminals, so I would appreciate someone teaching me what I am doing wrong.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783587/pip-install-cannot-combine-user-and-target), whose solution is to reinstall Python from the website, not from the Microsoft app store, but I am pretty sure I downloaed Python from the website. Should I re-download or would that cause more complication?