# Python Trying to install packages into local directory failes

Tags: python, aws-lambda, conda

I am trying to get the requirements for my code into a local package following this guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

In step one when I try to run a similar command `pip install --target ./package -r requirements.txt` it fails with the following error "ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'". I have no idea why it is complaining.

I am using PyCharm, with a conda environment, and I am running the commands in the PyCharm Terminal.

I found this question/answer: [PIP Install: Cannot combine --user and --target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783587/pip-install-cannot-combine-user-and-target)
but I am not using the Microsoft store version of python. My PyCharm project is configured to use the Anaconda python interpreter.

Update: I was able to get the command to succeed by installing pip inside of the conda environment I am using but I am still not sure why it was an issue before. If anyone has any details it would be appreciated.

Let me know what details are needed, thanks.

Comment: @Shawn That is the question I linked that I already checked. I do not have python installed through the Microsoft store.

Comment: Does your `requirements.txt` have a `--user` flag? The point is that the `--user` flag directs packages to be installed in a specific location (centralized for the user); whereas `--target` tells it to install in another, hence `pip` doesn't know which to prioritize.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install them all in the same directory try:

`pip install -r requirements.txt -t ./package`

Comment: Okay, so I was able to get it to work by installing pip inside of the conda environment I am using. I don't understand what the issue was though.

Comment: Well if your using your anaconda python and not your anacondas pip it would make sense that there might be issues

Comment: So I don't understand what happened. I would type pip install xyz in the terminal and it would install fine but when I tried that command it would give the error. Do you have any insight on why this was the case?

Comment: Id just be guessing and dont want to steer you wrong but you could check pip's issues on github for an answer as to why - https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3826