# How to add requests package in aws lambda python framework using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests

I am trying to add the requests package using the command pipenv install requests. I see that it creates a Pipfile and Piplock. But when I try to execute the lambda function written in python, It gives me an error saying no module called requests found.

Comment: Might be useful: [Upcoming changes to the Python SDK in AWS Lambda | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/)

Comment: Please edit your Question to include details of how you included the Requests package in your Lambda function. (For example, whether you created a zip file and uploaded it to the function, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Serverless](https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/), which is my preference.

Or include the libraries that are not part of Python's standard library, such as requests, you can use [lambda's layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-create).

1. Create the zip:
   This is a zip that contains all the libraries you want the Lambda function to use. First, create a folder called `python`.

```
$ mkdir python
$ cd python
```

then, install the Python libraries you need in there. You can do this either with a single library:

```
pip install --target . requests
```

or with a list of libraries, i.e. `requirements.txt`

```
pip install --target . -r requirements.txt
```

Finally, zip everything up

```
zip -r dependencies.zip ../python
```

2. Create a layer:
   You can do this in the AWS console or in the CLI. Follow [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-layers.html).
3. Add the layer to the lambda function:
   This can be done with the `Add a layer` option in the lambda page, or follow [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-layers.html) if you want to use the CLI.

Comment: Instead of copying my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64462403/3390419) step by step, you could have linked to it?