# Lambda Layer with Paramiko Library says "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'paramiko'"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, paramiko, aws-lambda-layers

I am new to the AWS world. So apologies if, my question is or I am naive!

I am trying to send a file from an S3 bucket to a remote server using a Lambda function in AWS.

Steps I followed get the above error:

1. On my Windows 11 PC (with python 3.8 installed), I created a directory C:\Library\ParamikoLib
2. From the command prompt I executed the code "pip install paramiko" in the directory "C:\Library\ParamikoLib"
3. I zipped the folder "ParamikoLib" in the "C:\Library" directory
4. I logged into AWS Console, went to Lambda and Selected Layers, and Clicked "Create a Layer"
5. I gave the name "Myparamiko" with some description, uploaded the zip file "ParamikoLib.zip" from step 3
6. Selected "x86_64" as compatible architecture
7. Chose, Python 3.8 as runtime and created the layer
8. Copied the ARN from Step 7 above and went to Lambda (with Python 3.8 runtime) where my code is present
9. Code has "import paramiko" followed by an empty line followed by lambda definition
10. When I test the code, I get the above error "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'paramiko'"

My Code Snippet

```
import paramiko

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Testing Paramiko Import")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for looking into this and helping me out!

Comment: The [layer path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) is language-specific. For Python dependencies, it's under the `python/` folder e.g. `python/lib/python3.9/site-package/xyz`

Comment: I tried to zip the Paramiko package that was under the below directory and uploaded that to a layer and even that solution did not work. I assume it is the same as the one that you were referring to as well.

C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages

Comment: Between steps 8 and 9 did you actually configure the Lambda function to use the layer? Other than that, I'd carefully follow the instructions for packaging and using the layer.

Comment: I am sure I did configure Lambda to use the ARN for the layer that I created. Every time I tried uploading different zip files to the layer, I ensured I carefully copied that ARN and updated Lambda accordingly to test it out!

Comment: Update your post to show the folders and contents of the layer ZIP file. And make sure that your (Windows?) version of zip isn't doing something odd.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS python lambda function:No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991117/aws-python-lambda-functionno-module-named-requests)