# Unable to import module paramiko in lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I wrote a lambda function that starts like this:

```
from paramikoimport SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy, RSAKey
```

I am trying to import this module as a layer, but it still does not work. It keeps showing me that there is no module named paramiko.

I followed this guide: [Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html)

I execute this command:

```
pip3 install paramiko -t .
```

into the `python/` folder and then compress everything and load it onto a layer.

Do you have any ideas to suggest to me? Do you see anything wrong with this procedure?

EDIT:
pip3 install command:

```
pip3 install paramiko -t .
Collecting paramiko
  Using cached paramiko-2.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (212 kB)
Collecting cryptography>=2.5
  Using cached cryptography-37.0.4-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.2 MB)
Collecting bcrypt>=3.1.3
  Using cached bcrypt-4.0.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (594 kB)
Collecting pynacl>=1.0.1
  Using cached PyNaCl-1.5.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl (856 kB)
Collecting six
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.12
  Using cached cffi-1.15.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (427 kB)
Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, cryptography, bcrypt, pynacl, six, paramiko
ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.
 
We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.
 
boto3 1.24.38 requires botocore<1.28.0,>=1.27.38, but you'll have botocore 1.23.54 which is incompatible.
awsebcli 3.20.3 requires six<1.15.0,>=1.11.0, but you'll have six 1.16.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed bcrypt-4.0.0 cffi-1.15.1 cryptography-37.0.4 paramiko-2.11.0 pycparser-2.21 pynacl-1.5.0 six-1.16.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS python lambda function:No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991117/aws-python-lambda-functionno-module-named-requests)

Comment: Sure, the steps are the same, they just don't work for this library, that's another problem.

Comment: The error *no module named paramiko* means you haven't packaged properly.

Comment: Exactly. Hence the question. Where do I fail in preparing it?

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64462403/3390419 step by step

Comment: I have already followed this guide. It still doesn't work for me

Comment: I found this [arn public layer paramiko](https://github.com/jetbridge/paramiko-lambda-layer).  They put public layers. This way it works.