# How to use PIL (pillow) with libraqm in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library

I have a simple code which writes some text on an image. I have uploaded all the required files as a zip package and the imported dependencies as layers.

One dependency - PIL needs `libraqm` to work and I am unable to figure out how to add that dependency. In my local system I installed `libraqm` with apt.

What I tried till now

1. Downloaded libraqm v 0.6 by using an unofficial rpm build. It did not resolve the issue.
2. Manually build the latest libraqm from the official github source. Did not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS python lambda function:No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991117/aws-python-lambda-functionno-module-named-requests)

Comment: @Foo no. He was facing issue in importing a library, while I don't have a library that I can import. libraqm is installed in the system.