# (AWS Lambda - Python) Running into issue attempting to import numpy through a custom layer

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-lambda

For a variety of reasons, I must use a custom layer to import numpy into my Lambda function. I am able to create other layers from which Lambda is able to import libraries without issue, but when attempting to import numpy, I run into the following error:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
```

I am really stumped on this issue with numpy and Lambda and would appreciate any help!

The following are some points which may be helpful in determining the issue:

- The numpy wheel I am creating the custom layer package from is: `https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/8c/1c5a2bbfb55e4ff35f9c30933e8816b188de3cc3e2eaf9304906991984a9/numpy-1.26.2-pp39-pypy39_pp73-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`
- Using `platform.uname()`, I am able to confirm that I am on the correct x86_64 architecture: `(system='Linux', node='169.254.84.165', release='4.14.255-327-266.539.amzn2.x86_64', version='#1 SMP Sun Oct 22 13:13:51 UTC 2023', machine='x86_64')`
- The package structure of the zipped numpy package used for the numpy layer is: `python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/<extracted numpy wheel contents>`
- According to `sys.executable` within Lambda, the python executable is at the following path: `/var/lang/bin/python3.10`
- According to `__file__` from libraries which are able to be imported without issue, the directory in which all dependencies are in is `/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages`
- Further, the following is the contents of the `/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages` directory:

```
['Bio', 'BioSQL', 'PyYAML-6.0.1.dist-info', '__pycache__', '_distutils_hack', '_yaml', 'bio-1.6.0.dist-info', 'biopython-1.81.dist-info', 'biorun', 'biothings_client', 'biothings_client-0.3.1.dist-info', 'certifi', 'certifi-2023.7.22.dist-info', 'charset_normalizer', 'charset_normalizer-3.3.2.dist-info', 'dateutil', 'distutils-precedence.pth', 'easy_install.py', 'gprofiler', 'gprofiler_official-1.0.0.dist-info', 'idna', 'idna-3.4.dist-info', 'mygene', 'mygene-3.2.2.dist-info', 'numpy', 'numpy-1.26.2.dist-info', 'numpy.libs', 'packaging', 'packaging-23.2.dist-info', 'pandas', 'pandas-2.1.3.dist-info', 'pip', 'pip-23.3.1.dist-info', 'pkg_resources', 'platformdirs', 'platformdirs-4.0.0.dist-info', 'pooch', 'pooch-1.8.0.dist-info', 'python_dateutil-2.8.2.dist-info', 'pytz', 'pytz-2023.3.post1.dist-info', 'requests', 'requests-2.31.0.dist-info', 'setuptools', 'setuptools-50.3.2.dist-info', 'six-1.16.0.dist-info', 'six.py', 'tqdm', 'tqdm-4.66.1.dist-info', 'tzdata', 'tzdata-2023.3.dist-info', 'urllib3', 'urllib3-1.26.18.dist-info', 'yaml']
```

Comment: Have you tried using the AWS-provided layer? See: [How to import numpy using layer in lambda aws?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75138632/174777)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Unfortunately, the AWS environment that my Lambda function exists within does not have access to the AWS provided layer