# Scalable event scheduler for possibly hundreds of thousands of events

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, cloud

I am trying to build a restaurant reservation application. A user can reserve a table in a restaurant ahead of time and will get a reminder 30 minutes prior. I am planning to use AWS SNS for sending the reminders. I am aware of AWS EventBridge rules, but it has a limitation of 300 rules per bus and 100 event buses per account. That makes a total of 30000 rules at any given time. A workaround can be a polling worker, which keep on querying a DB for events very 'n' seconds. Is there any event based mechanism other than AWS EventBridge which supports hundreds of thousands of events or is polling based implementation the only way forward ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using polling based approach. I used a t2 small EC2 instance and 2 SQS Queues. All events scheduled are pushed to an input SQS queue. A listener ( python script ) that runs on the EC2 polls the queue every 1 minute. Once an incoming event schedule is detected, it is pushed to a local SQLite DB, where event's scheduled time is indexed. The EC2 listener also polls the DB every one minute to check for events that needs to be triggered. The event is then put into the second SQS queue and a lambda function is added to trigger on SQS.

Answer (score 3):

> I am aware of AWS EventBridge rules, but it has a limitation of 300 rules per bus and 100 event buses per account. That makes a total of 30000 rules at any given time.

Just to correct this, 300 rules per bus is the soft limit and you can increase the quota. I think it's up to 2000.

[image: Amazon EventBridge Service Quotas]

But we cannot change the 100 event buses per account limit. After you increase the rules limit with the [EventBridge Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rules.html) you could make 2,000 * 100 = 200,000 rules.

But recently(10-Nov-2022) AWS launched a new service called [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html). I think this is what you are looking for, you can schedule up to 1 million soft limits, which means it's also adjustable, and also no event bus is needed.

[image: Amazon EventBridge Scheduler Service Quotas]

Here is the comparison chart of [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html) vs [EventBridge Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rules.html) taken from [Introducing Amazon EventBridge Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/) article.

[image]

Hope this new service will fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can now (as per 2022-11-10) use the [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html) to create schedulers per user.

> EventBridge Scheduler allows you to schedule millions of tasks that
> can invoke more than 270 AWS services and over 6,000 API operations.