# How do I schedule a Lambda function to execute everyday only during specific dates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

Is there a way to schedule my Lambda to run everyday ONLY during specific dates ?
Example:

- everyday between 1-July to 30-July
- everyday between 1-Oct to 30-Dec

Also, could I use these dates to set the schedule expression with eventbridge - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/example_eventbridge_PutRule_section.html?

Comment: Please try those expressions and let us know what did you discover.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Lambda Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382009/aws-lambda-scheduled-tasks)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below cron expression to trigger the lambda function between 1-July and to 30-July

```
0 0 1-30 7 ? *
```

Explanation of the cron expression:

- The first field is for minutes (0).
- The second field is for hours (0).
- The third field is for days of the month (1-30).
- The fourth field is for months (7, July).
- The fifth field is for days of the week (? means every day).
- The sixth field is for years (* means every year).

You can refer attached image:

[image: Event bridge Cron expression config]

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a rule to run an AWS Lambda function on a schedule. Here is a [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) that shows how to do it.

At a high level, here are the steps.

1. Create an AWS Lambda Function
2. Create a Rule via CloudWatch
3. Verify the Rule