# How to run a python program only at specific hours with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, algorithmic-trading

I have a python trading bot that needs to run only durring market hours (9:30-4:30) and it needs to stop and start automatically. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance!

I looked through the AWS website and could not find anything.

Comment: How are you hosting this?  EC2, Lambda, etc?

Comment: I have not implemented this on AWS but I am looking into using Lambda

Comment: While I'm not 100% sure what you're going to be doing with it, I'd look at scheduling something with the [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html).  That can run your Lambda at the schedule you want.  Depending on where you're at in the world, watch for possible time changes for daylight savings time.  And remember that a Lambda is limited to 15 minutes of run time but will scale to potentially thousands of simultaneous instances.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Lambda Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382009/aws-lambda-scheduled-tasks)

Answer (score -2):

to achieve this is by using Python's schedule library along with a system-level task scheduler like cron on Unix-based systems or Task Scheduler on Windows

You need to follow the following steps:
#install the sheduler library
pip install schedule

#write you trade bot script and make sure that it contain trade logic and be able to interact with the market and perform trading operations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).